# Is it true that $A = QQ^{T}$, $Q$ a square matrix, is invertible if and only if $A$ is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that $A = QQ^{T}$ ($A$, $Q$ square matrices) is positive definite if and only if $Q$ is invertible for every choice of $Q$. Since the product of invertible matrices is invertible, would it be safe for me to say that $A = QQ^{T}$ is invertible if and only if $A$ is positive definite?

Comment: No, clearly $A^T=A$, so you need that $A$ is symmetric as well.

Comment: @QuangHoang Huh?

Comment: nvm, somehow I thought OP asked for the decomposition $A=QQ^T$. So need my afternoon coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need that $Q^T$ is invertible if and only if $Q$ is, but sure.

Note that it is very easy to see your result directly: one direction is trivial, and for the other, take any $v\neq 0$ and compute the inner product $v^TAv$.